# How to switch position of div in directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that renders the following structure
[image: Directive output]

In Div1 I have some content and in Div2 some other content. There is a splitter in the middle. I need a function to swap the div positions Div1 in Div2 position and vice versa. What as some good ways to do this in Angular directive ?

One way i can think of is using ng-switch, but will have to do some reputable stuff... any other good ways ? Some animation during switching would be cool.

No jQuery allowed. Following is the demo fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gauravsoni/z9gz1wgy/

Sample code:

```
 angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.orientation = "horizontal";
  $scope.hello = "Hello from Controller!";
})

.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return{
    template:'<div kendo-splitter><div>1st pane</div><div>2nd pane</div></div>'
}
})
```

**UPDATE:**
I am using the following code to do the switching,

```
<button ng-click='toggle = !toggle'>Switch View</button>
<div ng-if="toggle">
    <div>
        Left side 
    </div>
    <div>
        right side
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!toggle">
    <div>
        right side 
    </div>
    <div>
        left side
    </div>
</div>
```

So based on the toggle value appropriate div gets activated , only drawback here is i have to write the view 2 times.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: @Jesse ok, adding fiddle 5 min.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flexbox` and define an order for the elements. Then use angular to toggle a class on the container. You could also use floats or some other CSS technique to mess around with the order, but the idea is to use CSS for this.

See demo below.
http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/ZbWeNV

**Template**

```
<div ng-app="demo">

  <columns></columns>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="columns.html">
    <div>
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column column-one">Col 1</div>
        <div class="column column-two">Col 2</div>
      </div>
      <button ng-click="swap()">Swap</button>
    </div>
  </script>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
}
.column-one { order: 1; }
.column-two { order: 2; }

.swapped {
  .column-one { order: 2; }
  .column-two { order: 1; }
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module("demo", [])
  .directive("columns", function() {

    return {
      templateUrl: "columns.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.swap = function() {
          element.toggleClass("swapped");
        }

      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: It does not seem to be switching for me .. can you pls check Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Did you try the demo link I sent? Works fine for me on Chrome OS X

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular [ui sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) on this. You can easily drag and sort them. You can place handlers so only portion of div is able to drag the divs.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, ones cleaner than others obviously.

If there are no other factors that can affect the method, that you use to resolve this problem and  If the task is as simple as just switch positions, I guess you can define the container div (the one that contains both smaller divs) as flexbox with

```
display:flex
```

and

```
flex-flow: row nowrap,
```

and then on hover, or on scroll, or toggle, or whatever it is... change 
`flex-flow` to `flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap`

If you need a bit of animation effect you can add transition: .5 to container div

Sorry if I'm not clear :(